# Which $y$ is the zero vector that gives $x + \mathbf0 = \max{(x, \mathbf0)}= x$ for every $x$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

This was a note in my Linear Algebra textbook after the column space chapter. I'm so confused. Is the answer: "$y$ is the $n$ dimensional column vector where each element is negative infinity." ?

*Note* : An interesting “max-plus” vector space comes from the real numbers $\mathbf R$ combined with $-\infty$. Change addition to give $x + y = \max{(x, y)}$ and change multiplication to $xy =$ usual $x + y$. Which $y$ is the zero vector that gives $x + 0 = \max{(x, 0)} = x$ for every $x$?

[edit: here is a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viTIz.png)

Comment: Is this tropical algebra? That certainly is not a vector space operation.

Comment: The answer is $-\infty$, except the question is ill posed because it's just not a vector space. Is this translated from another language?

Comment: @MattSamuel Okay thanks. No it's not translated, literally a note in the answer key. I'm studying normal linear algebra so it's definitely not tropical algebra.

Comment: Well that's basically the definition of a tropical ring. Maybe the author was studying tropical algebra while writing this and hastily added this confused note.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the insight. The author is Gilbert Strang.

Comment: http://www-math.mit.edu/~gs/ The author is no slouch but I guess everybody makes mistakes!